# Displayed | ActivityTaskManager not showing specific Activity in logcat

Tags: android, android-activity

I have 3 activities. ActivityA, ActivityB & ActivityC.

From ActivityA button click I am opening ActivityB. On ActivityB onCreate ActivityC is opening.

When I type Displayed in Logcat ideally ActivityA, ActivityB & ActivityC all should show on clicking button on ActivityA. However ActivityA & ActivityC is only getting displayed. Any reasons for this?

```
2022-05-18 18:02:01.347 2044-2153/? I/ActivityTaskManager: Displayed com.libs.a6maytestapp/.activities.ActivityA: +454ms
2022-05-18 18:02:03.296 2044-2153/? I/ActivityTaskManager: Displayed com.libs.a6maytestapp/.activities.ActivityC: +150ms
```

Comment: Same question, need some help.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time) since Activity B called Activity C in onCreate the output should be in the form

```
2022-05-18 18:02:03.296 2044-2153/? I/ActivityTaskManager: Displayed com.libs.a6maytestapp/.activities.ActivityC: +150ms (total +643ms)
```

where the extra total would be the sum of Activity B + Activity C. But in your case I would guess that's summed up in the reading of Activity C itself.